# Solana py - Websocket Subscription to GetTokenAccountBalance

Tags: websocket, solana-py

Based on my research, I came to know that encoding = "base64" would solve the error "solders.SerdeJSONError: a list or single element". But when we try to subscribe to GetTokeAccountBalance, we''re not able to pass "encoding". It says unexpected argument has been recieved, which does make sense. There must be something wrong inside the package. Would you be able to give suggestions or any quick solutions for this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Consider updating your question with your code and the exact error message you've encountered, so that a community member can more easily spot the error.